# Force a null into non-nullable type

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to jam a null into a non-nullable type with some sort of "I know what I'm doing"?

I want to make a doubly linked list:

```
data class Node(var prev: Node, var next: Node, val value: Int)
```

I can guarantee that this list will have at least two elements at all times *except* during initialization, after the first node has been added but before the second node.  I'd like to make the guarantee that prev and next will never be null.

One thing I thought I'd try is to write a special constructor that initializes both the first and second nodes `constructor(v1: Int, v2: Int) : this(Node(this, this, v1), v2)`, but that doesn't work because I can't do anything with `this` before entering the body.

Comment: You could use lateinit, but that would require manually setting it (and taking it out of the primary constructor). `by lazy` might also be an option, but AFAIK, it can't be used in the primary constructor either

Comment: Aha! lateinit seems to be the way to go.  See my answer -- I came up with a pretty overhead-heavy way of doing this but lateinit reduces each property back down to 1 line.  I'll happily upvote/accept as answer if you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if we're doing the same [adventofcode puzzle](https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/9) in kotlin

I used lateinit properties to allow the marble to change its position as a node in a linked list

```
class Marble(val marbleNumber: Long) {
    lateinit var counterClockwiseMarble: Marble
    lateinit var clockwiseMarble: Marble
}
```

initially with setters

```
class Marble(val marbleNumber: Long) {
    lateinit var counterClockwiseMarble: Marble
      private set

    lateinit var clockwiseMarble: Marble
      private set

    fun setCounterClockwise(m: Marble) {
      this.counterClockwiseMarble = m
    }

    fun setClockwise(m: Marble) {
      this.clockwiseMarble = m
    }
}
```

but that seemed like a lot of text when usage was controlled enough to be safe

If it is the same puzzle you can [see this used in context on github](https://github.com/pauldambra/adventofcode2018/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/dambra/adventofcode2018/day9/Circle.kt)

Comment: [Indeed](https://bitbucket.org/mj3ngr/adventofcode/src/259f569f49ce0392fbe9a8fc5fff5f4e10615d3d/src/mj3ngr/adventofcode/y2018/day9/Day9.kt#lines-15:16) :) -- lateinit seems to be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I can create properties with null-able backing fields.

```
data class Node(val value: Int) {
  private var _prev: Node? = null
  var prev: Node
    get() = _prev!!
    set(value) {
      _prev = value
    }

  private var _next: Node? = null
  var next: Node
    get() = _next!!
    set(value) {
      _next = value
    }

  constructor(prev: Node, next: Node, value: Int) : this(value) {
    this.prev = prev
    this.next = next
    prev.next = this
    next.prev = this
  }
}
```

This can then be initialized via

```
val node0 = Node(0)
val node1 = Node(node0, node0, 1)
```

I'm hoping to learn the overhead can be reduced a little bit, but this is better than null-able next/prev.

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract the way a `Node` holds its references by providing an interface or a `sealed class` e.g.

```
data class Node(val ref: Reference, val value: Int)

sealed class Reference {
    class Forward(val next: Node): Reference()
    class Backward(val prev: Node): Reference()
    class Bidirection(val prev: Node, val next: Node): Reference()
}
```

This approach will negate your need for nullable types. It is not very performant, but a declarative way to get compile time type-safety.